# Forgot to assign letter during partition creation. Now can't see it?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I had two partition disks on my system (something like this)

```
 disk    |  status  |  size   |   free
---------|----------|---------|---------
 disk 0  |  online  |  900gb  |  100gb
 disk 1  |  online  |  10gb   |
```

While creating a new partition I did this :

- Select Disk 0
- Create partition primary size = xxxx
- exit

In this process, I forgot to assign a letter to new partition and now the new partition is not displaying.

Can anyone help out for the solution ?

Comment: You did it through `Windows Partition manager` or through command-line ? Also please provide the Windows version you are using any other details that may help out.

Comment: See if [this](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/drive-letter-is-missing-in-windows.html) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to diskpart and then

```
Sel disk 0
list par
```

If the partition is still there diskpart will show it.

Then just:

```
Sel par #
assign letter=x
```

If the partition isn't there then you somehow managed to remove it, so re-create and assign.

Comment: these text editors they use are crap.  "Sel disk 0"  <enter>, then next line type   "list par" <enter>.  If the partition is there then select it and assign a letter. -larryc

Comment: Just read the [formatting help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) to learn about Stack Exchange style Markdown. Also, we don’t do signature, taglines, or greetings around here.